# Merge sorted files into single sorted file in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have 10 files that was created by mapreduce. They are sorted by LongInt key. I want to merge these files into single file. So they should be sorted.

I tried **getmerge** command. But it is not useful. Because final file is not sorted. It only paste files into single file without any sorted. So, what is the solution?

**Answer**

use this command:

```
sort -mnr <src>
```

Also you can visit this [sort command in linux](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_sort.htm)

Comment: Why can't you run the map reduce job with 1 reducer?

Comment: Because it takes lot of time

Answer (score 0):

Since the output data is large, getting files to local machine and sorting is not a good option. I think you should write you own `Partitioner`, that splits the keys in a non-overlapping range. For example [0-1000] [1000-2000] .....

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps shown below, after your MR job is executed:

1. Merge the output contents using the following commands:

   ```
   hadoop fs -cat [dir]/* | hadoop fs -put - [destination file]
   ```
2. Sort the output (of step 1) using a MR job that does TotalSort (Multiple reducers can be used - Scalability wouldn't be affected)
3. Merge the output (of step 2) using:

   ```
   hadoop -getmerge command or 
   hadoop fs -cat [dir]/* | hadoop fs -put - [destination file]
   ```

Step 2 can be achieved with this code [link](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.0.3/src/examples/org/apache/hadoop/examples/Sort.java?view=markup)

Answer (score 0):

You can merge files but merged file will not be sorted. However, you can write a map-reduce job and sort your data into a single output.

I mean:

1. merge files

   `hadoop fs -getmerge /output/dir/on/hdfs/esired/local/output/file.txt`

   or

   give input directory to a Map-Reduce Job. It merges files as the above command.
2. Write a Map-Reduce job to sort data.